# CryptoJS - AES encryption performance to slow

Tags: javascript, performance, encryption, aes, cryptojs

Im using this CryptoJs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js to) encryt data in Javascript (Decryption is later on done in .net backend)

I'm encrypting 5'000'000 records one by one with the following code:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(field, encryptionParams.communicationKey, {
      iv: encryptionParams.communicationIV,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
});
```

It's way slower than expected (15 minutes)

Is there any performance boost possible? In my opinion it gets exponentially slower the higher the iteration count and sounds similar to that issue here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/issues/65

I'm using chromium engine on electron.

Comment: I'd try a few different libs. I haven't tried AES, but some hashing algos I've used in JS varied quite a bit in performance depending on the lib.

Comment: @Marc Why are you even encrypting in a browser (client application) to send it to the server? Don't you use TLS? If not, then you really should and then you wouldn't need to use any additional manual encryption of records.

Comment: @ArtjomB. My customer required an additional encryption to send the data via TLS :-(

Comment: I see. Try the WebCrypto API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API

Comment: @ArtjomB.Based on this page WebCrypto is pretty slow: https://medium.com/@encryb/comparing-performance-of-javascript-cryptography-libraries-42fb138116f3#.k0fg8ls01

Comment: @MarcThomann according to that page, they say WebCrypto is the opposite of what you're claiming

Comment: @SnareHanger is right